# The segmentation fault in malloc_trim(0) when run ASAN

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, pthreads, address-sanitizer

The code 1.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void* thread_function(void* arg) {
    char* ptr = (char *)malloc(10);
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
    free(ptr);
    malloc_trim(0);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[2];

    for (long i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_function, (void*)i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compile use -fsanitize=address
gcc -pthread -o ASANtest -fsanitize=address -O1 1.c
And then run ASANtest multiple times. An error occured.

The error information:

```
bash-4.4$ ./ASANtest
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==7076==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000008 (pc 0x7f95439d87d9 bp 0x000000000fff sp 0x7f953f8fde00 T2)
==7076==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==7076==Hint: address points to the zero page.
#0 0x7f95439d87d8 in malloc_trim (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x9e7d8)
#1 0x400a8f in thread_function (/workspace/git/ehaauwn/PCPB-22713/2024/eric-pc-routing-engine/raas/product/docker/build/ASANtest+0x400a8f)
#2 0x7f9543d396e9 in start_thread (/lib64/libpthread.so.0+0xa6e9)
#3 0x7f9543a51a8e in clone (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x117a8e)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x9e7d8) in malloc_trim
Thread T2 created by T0 here:
#0 0x7f9543f8bc80 in pthread_create (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.4+0x39c80)
#1 0x400b32 in main (/workspace/git/ehaauwn/PCPB-22713/2024/eric-pc-routing-engine/raas/product/docker/build/ASANtest+0x400b32)
#2 0x400d13 in _IO_stdin_used (/workspace/git/ehaauwn/PCPB-22713/2024/eric-pc-routing-engine/raas/product/docker/build/ASANtest+0x400d13)

==7076==ABORTING
```

If I compile without -fsanitize=address  , the program runs  normally.

I want to know if the malloc_trim function has any security risks, or if there are any bugs in ASAN

Comment: Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). [Edit] your question to copy-paste the output *as text*.

Comment: Is `malloc_trim` guaranteed to be thread-safe? Everything from malloc.h is old obsolete gunk, iirc.

Comment: On another couple of notes, `<malloc.h>` is not a standard C heder file. In C you [don't need to (and really shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And if you don't use the thread function argument, pass `NULL` instead. Oh, and please make sure your code is consistently indented. And don't add things you don't need in your [mre] (like that unused mutex).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well they need it for `malloc_trim`. But if they actually need `malloc_trim` is another story.

Comment: ASAN works by replacing the `malloc` family functions, but `malloc_trim` is a non-standard glibc functionality. Is ASAN even aware of it? I doubt it. Then it wouldn't be surprising that it isn't supported.

Comment: In fact yes, @Lundin.  [The manual page for `malloc_trim()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) says it is thread safe.

Comment: @user17732522, you're quite right that `malloc_trim()` is a glibc extension, and it is indeed plausible that it does not interoperate properly with ASAN.  But that would be a bug, on one side or the other, which would be at least *a little* surprising.  Enabling ASAN is not supposed to break correct programs.

Answer (score 0):

As previous commenters said, `malloc_trim` is a GLIBC extension, which Address Sanitizer knows nothing about.

I just checked: as of this moment `malloc_trim` is not mentioned at all anywhere in `compiler-rt/lib/asan/`.

When you call `malloc_trim`, you get the GLIBC version, which crashes because GLIBC `malloc` internals have not been initialized (because Address Sanitizer *replaces* GLIBC `malloc`).

It would be trivial for ASan developers to intercept `malloc_trim` and do nothing when it is called, but they probably haven't seen this reported yet.

So do report it in the appropriate bug tracker, and in the mean time you should *likely* remove all calls to `malloc_trim` -- it is *very unlikely* that these calls are doing anything useful in your program.